# How to construct a javax.jms.TextMessage in unit tests?

Tags: java, unit-testing, jms

What is the best way to construct a [TextMessage](https://jms-spec.java.net/2.0/apidocs/javax/jms/TextMessage.html) from a String in a unit test?

I see only [Session#createTextMessage(String)](https://jms-spec.java.net/2.0/apidocs/javax/jms/Session.html#createTextMessage()), but that requires a session which requires some setup.

The alternative is just to mock the TextMessage, but I thought it is a good practice to avoid mocking data objects.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try to use the constructor for your broker's implementation of `TextMessage`.

For example, if you use **ActiveMQ**, you could create a new `ActiveMQTextMessage` object via the default constructor, and use the `setText` setter to set the payload.

See http://activemq.apache.org/maven/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/command/ActiveMQTextMessage.html.

If the broker library is not in the classpath of your unit tests, nor you intend to include it, you'll have no other option than to mock it, given that the JMS API doesn't come with a default implementation.

Using a mock in this situation is perfectly valid and reasonable.

Comment: Thanks, do you know if there is an option for HornetQ?

Comment: Have a look at http://hornetq.sourceforge.net/docs/hornetq-2.0.0.CR2/api/org/hornetq/jms/client/HornetQTextMessage.html, although it requires a ClientSession, you could try and pass null. However, this is a fragile and dirty approach, because even if HornetQ didn't complain about a null value, it could in future versions.

Comment: I suggest using a mock. It should be simple and cleaner to implement. What is the reason you want to avoid a mock? TextMessage is not a data object, it is part of an API which you don't control.

Comment: If it is common to use a mock here, I would do the same. Well, TextMessage looks like a wrapper of a string message. That is why I considered it to be a data object.